# Best way to organize/architect a web site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

I have to take a key decision about our web site organization/architecture.

Here is my context.
Our main web site will be available in different countries. Even if the Business is nearly the same, there are some region-specific features. Of course it concerns translations, but also master/layouts and business process. These difference are because of different legislations. At the beginning we will have 4 or 5 derivations, but the target could be 20.

A simple comparison could be Stackoverflow and the Stack Exchange Network. Main features are quite the same between website, but there are site-specific business rules.

To my mind, there are basically two possible approachs :

- **Having a single web site that manage region/country-specific features**.
  The will keep core features on the same site, but will involve coupling between all regions. There is also a risk of "IF" in the code. Devs & Maintainability is optimal (unique fix for all) but risky (could break others). A way to do this is a combinaison of portable areas and a custom view engine (generic view template in parent folder and derivation in a sub folder)
- **Having one web site per region/country** 
  There will be a common web site that will be implemented. There will have some common components but each web site will have its own lifecycle; Devs & Maintainability is easier but costly (if there are many derivations)

Please Note, another impact of this organization is deployment and avaibility.

What is the best way to organize this ?

Edit :
We already have some experiences in MVC and as a general guideline, we are aware of MVC Best Practices : thin controllers, DI, ViewModels, Action Filters, ...

Comment: a centralized data structure which will be handled by a webserver with xml and xslt in background or xmlrpc server ... xml will help you a lot to dynamically create what exactly you need on each website you want to present to the public and will help a lot with maintenance, development and security ...

Comment: not sure to understand your solution. could you explain a little bit ?

Comment: We're using Unity2 Dependency Injection to manage our "portal".

Comment: @Jeff Of course, see edit. What are you injecting in your portail ?

Comment: This is a very subjective question.  There is never a "best" way, but a combination of tradeoffs that you might, under your specific circumstances, consider to be "better" or "worse."

Comment: We're injecting Membership, Mail, Messaging, Invoice, Blob, etc -services, and the container key is based on subdomains that our clients use. Honestly I can't tell you very much as I am not too familiar with it, in fact I am not even sure if container key is the right terminology (my boss built the architecture/infrastructure of our project).